# Keyword SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, keyword-search

I am fairly new to SQL Server but I have to write a stored procedure that will search a specific table with a list of keywords and it is suppose to return the rows which a hit has been found, I wrote a query which works but the problems is when I have to amend the keyword list then I have to start from scratch with writing the query.

The query is as follows

```
SELECT * 
INTO [playground].[dbo].[New table name] 
FROM [playground].[dbo].[Main table]
WHERE [Document Type Description] LIKE 'Alcohol' 
   OR [Document Type Description] LIKE 'DSTV' 
   OR [Document Type Description] LIKE 'Entertainment' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Bday' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Birthday' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Bar' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Booze' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Catering' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Farewell' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Food' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Function' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Meals' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Year end functions' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Womens day' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Womans day' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Tuck shop' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Teambuilding' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Refreshment' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Liquor' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Lunch' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Water' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Bread' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Breakaway' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Canteen' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Gifts' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Glass' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Glasses' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Glassware' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Ticket' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Rugby' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Cricket' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Tea cups' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Tea' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Sugar bowl' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Sugar' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Soup bowls' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Side plate' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Serving tray' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Saucers' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Tray' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Non slip tray' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Milk' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Milk jug' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Mugs' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Dessert' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Dessert spoons' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Dinner set' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Jug' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Kent' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Knifes' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Knives' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Cooler boxes' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Crockery' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Christmas' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Coffee' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Popcorn machine' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Cooler' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Freezer' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Fridge' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Fan ' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Extraction fan' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Heaters' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Water cooler' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Washing machine' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Warmer' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Vacuum cleaner' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Urn' OR
[Document Type Description]like'Thermostat'
```

Ultimately I wish that I have a SP that will read the array of keywords and let me choose which tables column to search for in the main tables

Hope this makes sense 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Put those strings in a TABLE and JOIN on equality with [Document Type Description]  You can add another column to control their inclusion.

Comment: @AlexK. the OP is using `like`, not equality. Is there a way to do what you described using `like` comparison semantic in SQL Server?

Comment: Actually he is looking for equality (there are no wildcards, he says it works as expected) - And yes you can `JOIN T ON X LIKE '%' + Y + '%'` -

Comment: do you need 'like' or equality? if you gonna use like - add % before and after the search string `[Document Type Description] like '%Thermostat%'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of ideas on your code.

**The use of `LIKE`**
The way you put your query it actually performs an equality check, as you put no wildcards in your `LIKE` statement. This causes two problems:

1. You may not get the results you expect
2. You may not be using indices (which would speed things up) because you use `LIKE`

First of all you need to decide whether you want to check for equality or whether the field searched should just *contain* the string you're looking for.

If you want an equality check, use

```
... WHERE [Field] = 'value'
```

instead of

```
... WHERE [Field] LIKE 'value'
```

**Equality checks**
There are a couple of way of speeding them up. You could put the search terms in a table and do something like this:

```
... WHERE [Field] in (SELECT Term FROM TableOfSearchTerms)
```

Or you could even try to join the two tables together. Then you don't need a `WHERE` clause at all:

```
... FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN TableOfSearchTerms terms ON terms.Term = t1.[Field]
```

**Making the search field dynamic**
This is not so easy. You *could* create a dynamic SQL statement as string and then use `EXEC` to execute this, but you have to be careful not to introduce problems (like SQL injections, etc.).

**Performing an actual `LIKE`**
In that case, you'd need to use wildcards in your statement, like this:

```
... WHERE [Field] LIKE `%searchterm%`
```

This is not so easy to solve using the things I've said above. In that case (even though it hurts me to say) it would probably be easiest to assemble a string that contains the query and execute this using `EXEC`. The result might look like this:

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(max)
SET @query = "INSERT INTO ... WHERE ";

EXEC (@query)
```

You could use a cursor on the search terms table to add the required `LIKE`s to the `WHERE` clause.